# downloading a file on click in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

**html**

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: arrayList">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.downloadLastFile">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**javascript**

```
    function ItemViewModel(item){
    if(!$.isEmptyObject(item)){
      var self = this;
      self.lastFile = ko.observable(item.file_name);    

      self.downloadLastFile = function(row) {
         console.log(row.lastFile());
         var link = document.createElement('a');
         link.href = data;
         link.download = row.lastFile();
         document.body.appendChild(link);
         link.click();
        }
     }
   }
function MainViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.arrayList= ko.observableArray();
}
dataModel = new MainViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(dataModel);
```

I am trying to download a file on clicking. This piece of code is not working. Can someone check?

Comment: There's no `ArrayList` property in your `ViewModel`, your `<span>` and `<a>` arenn't closed and there's a weird `("#download_div")` in your click handler. Please fix the obvious syntax errors in your code and provide all code relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- I can't see `self` variable defined in your model.
- Since I see `$parent` in your `click` binding I assume there should be a parent model where you defined and assign data to `ArrayList`.
- Since you are using `knockout click binding` you don't need to use `jquery` click binding inside knockout click function `("#download_div")` again. WRONG

Below just is an example how you can do it

Example :https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/114/

JS:

```
var data = [{id:1, file_name : "file_name1"},{id:2, file_name : "file_name2"}];

function AppViewModel(){
   var self = this;
   self.ArrayList = ko.observableArray($.map(data, function (item) {
          return new ItemViewModel(item);
    }));

   self.downloadLastFile = function(item) {
     console.log(item.lastFile());
     var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = data;
    //here you append your rootURL to the file name
    link.download = item.lastFile();
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
   }
 }

 var ItemViewModel = function(data){
   var self = this;
   self.lastFile = ko.observable(data.file_name);
 }

var viewModel = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Hey I have edited the question. Can you please see once again?

Comment: @lola the JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/114/ example that I provided is working perfectly. You should be able to look at it and modify your own code and make it work. in your updated question `ArrayList` never populated with your `ItemViewModel`. It is a better practice to define your click function inside the parent VM one time instead of being defined for every single of rows.